# Type Error occurred when creating object Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3

I have created custom module and it's working fine in **Dev**, but it's not working on **Production**. It's throwing Type error.

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor,
> Argument 5 passed to
> Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::__construct()
> must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
> or be null, string given, called in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
> on line 121 [] [] [2021-01-11 10:11:47] report.CRITICAL: Type Error
> occurred when creating object:
> Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor
> [] []

My collection file as below

```
<?php

namespace Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{

    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\Product',
            'Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product'
        );
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

and **di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="tiny_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tiny_pro</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Have you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`?

Comment: @dudzio Yes, compiled and working in dev. But not working in production.

Comment: In your `di.xml` try changing the `xsi:type` to `object` for the `resourceModel` argument

Comment: @Sam you shoud submit that as the answer. you are correct

Answer (score 11):

You are creating a virtual type with the namespace `Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` which already exists.

As a result, `AbstractFactory` will pass the arguments (`mainTable` and `resourceModel`) to the `__construct` function of `AbstractCollection` instead of `SearchResult`, which throws an exception because `AbstractCollection` does not accept the arguments as a string whereas `SearchResult` does.

To solve the problem, you have to rename the virtual type namespace to `Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Grid\Collection`.

See the code below:

```
<virtualType name="Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tiny_pro</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="tiny_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Flush cache with `php bin/magento c:f` and check again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This fixed my issue. However besides flushing the cache you should also recompile `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks @Lokesh

Comment: Fixed issue, Still want to understand what confliction is happening at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Within your `di.xml` for the `resourceModel` argument set the `xsi:type` to `object`. This will resolve the FQN to its relevant class.

```
<virtualType name="Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tiny_pro</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

If I'm not mistaken, the reason for it only happening when in production mode and not development mode. When in development mode Interceptors are generated on the fly, so if you never loaded your custom collection while testing you wouldn't see the error. Whereas in production mode it generates the Interceptors during the compilation step, so you would get the error before you can even deploy/access the site.

Comment: Thank you, let me try

Comment: this code is correct? or where to change xsi:type to object??

Comment: @BhaveshBhuva on the resourceModel argument tag

Answer (score 0):

try it:-

```
<?php

namespace Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product;


class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\Product',
        'Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product'
        );
        parent::_construct();
    }

}
```

> follow step:-

> php bin/magento s:up
>
> php bin/magento s:s:d -f
>
> php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your collection instance is receiving a string instead of a class as argument for resource model (5th argument).

Usually, magento uses `::class` to initialize model & resource model with `__init()` method call, you can try the code below to check if it solves your error with `string` argument vs `AdapterInterface` implementation argument :

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(
        \Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\Product::class,
        \Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product::class,
    );

    parent::_construct();
}
```

Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

On the di.xml

Check if you have the path like these "Vendor\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection" added to your item tag value.

```
 <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendor_blog_admin_ui_post_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

If so you will want to change it to something like this:

"VendorBlogCollection"

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendor_blog_admin_ui_post_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">VendorBlogCollection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

And then change the virtualType name to "VendorBlogCollection" as well.

```
<virtualType name="VendorBlogCollection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">vendor_blog_post</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Run php bin/magento se:up

Hope it works :)

Answer (score -1):

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score -1):

In mode production you must recompile to regenerate the new interceptor.

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If not work share please the content of the file:

Tiny\ProductCustomization\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor

Thanks