# Argument 5 passed to Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\PriceResult\Collection\Interceptor::__construct()

Tags: collection, controllers, model, dicompilation

I have created a custom module and it's working fine,if I only run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command. However, when I attempt to run `php bin/magento s:d:c` it raises an exception.

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\PriceResult\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\PriceResult\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface or be null, string given, called in /Users/macbook/Sites/magento243/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
Exception in /Users/macbook/Sites/magento243/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131
```

Here is my collection class

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\PriceResult;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\PriceResult::class,
            \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\PriceResult::class,
        );
    }
}
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\SyncPriceResult\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">price_result</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\SyncPriceResult</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="price_result_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\SyncPriceResult\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this issue, I made the adjustment by updating the virtual type namespace as follows:
`VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection`

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <virtualType name="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">price_result</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Grid</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="price_result_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This resource was also instrumental in helping me identify and address the problem:
[Type Error occurred when creating object Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/329446/type-error-occurred-when-creating-object-magento-2/#answer-329560)